# Using lmfit Minimizer.minimize() leads to error ValueError: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous"

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting, lmfit

I want to use lmfit to fit the function:

```
func(x,region,E0,C0,R1,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,alpha,beta,rho,theta,delta,d)
```

and get the information on confidence intervals of the parameters.
`func` takes as parameter `x` an float or an array of floats with values in between 0 and 78. The function calls an exe generated from a cpp-file. And from the outstream of this exe then returns an array of function values corresponding to the x-values.

I also have an array of data called `total_data_array` that I want to fit to. I am certain that `total_data_array` contains the correct values and has the correct size. The following is a shortened version of my code:

```
#Define fitting function
def func(x,region,E0,C0,R1,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,alpha,beta,rho,theta,delta,d):#x should be between 0 and 75
    print("Function called")
    print(E0,C0,R1,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,alpha,beta,rho,theta,delta,d)
    #Make x iterable if it is only a float/int
    if not hasattr(x,'__iter__'):
        x = np.array([x])
    result = []
    output = subprocess.check_output([r'...\model.exe', str(region),str(E0),str(C0),str(R1),str(R3),str(R4),str(R5),str(R6),str(R7),str(R8),str(alpha),str(beta),str(rho),str(theta),str(delta),str(d)])
    output_str = codecs.decode(output)
    output_str_list = output_str.split('\r\n')
    output_str_list.pop()
    dataarray = []
    index = 0
    for word in output_str_list:
        if index in range(416,624) or index in range(728,832):
            if word == '-nan(ind)':
                dataarray.append(0.0)
            else:
                dataarray.append(float(word))
        index+=1
    for x0 in x:
        y = dataarray(int(x0*4))
        result.append(y)
    return result

parameters = lmfit.Parameters()
parameters.add('region',value=1)
parameters.add('E0',value=500,min=0.0,max = 10000.0)
parameters.add('C0',value=200,min=0.0,max = 10000.0)
parameters.add('R1',value=0.587,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters.add('R3',value=0.3125,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters.add('R4',value=0.1666,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters.add('R5',value=0.1,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters.add('R6',value=0.2,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters.add('R7',value=0.4,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters.add('R8',value=0.125,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters.add('alpha',value=0.09,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters.add('beta',value=0.25,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters.add('rho',value=0.2,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters.add('theta',value=0.26,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters.add('delta',value=0.77,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters.add('d',value=0.99,min=0.0,max=1.0)
parameters['region'].vary = False

xData = np.arange(0, 78, 1)
#Running this part of the code works
my_model = lmfit.Model(func)
results = my_model.fit(total_data_array,params=parameters,x=xData)
```

Calling

```
results = my_model.fit(total_data_array, params=parameters,x=xData)
```

works  perfectly fine. Also the fit does look quite good. But I want to be able to view the confidence intervals of the parameters. As far as I know, there are two ways to achieve this.

1. **Using the model that I have** or
2. **Using Minimizers**.

**If I try the model approach**, adding the lines to my code:

```
    ci = lmfit.conf_interval(my_model,results)
    lmfit.report_ci(ci)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\paul1\OneDrive\Desktop\epidemiology\coding\Secihurd_Model\src\python\regional fitting\fitting2.py", line 128, in <module>
    ci = lmfit.conf_interval(my_model,results)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\lmfit\confidence.py", line 141, in conf_interval
    ci = ConfidenceInterval(minimizer, result, p_names, prob_func, sigmas,
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\confidence.py", line 185, in __init__
    raise MinimizerException(CONF_ERR_STDERR)
lmfit.minimizer.MinimizerException: Cannot determine Confidence Intervals without sensible uncertainty estimates
```

Plotting the `fit_reports` yields:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(func)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 511
    # data points      = 78
    # variables        = 15
    chi-square         = 34979.5187
    reduced chi-square = 555.230456
    Akaike info crit   = 506.253115
    Bayesian info crit = 541.603747
    R-squared          = 0.62955613
##  Warning: uncertainties could not be estimated:
[[Variables]]
    region:  1 (fixed)
    E0:      4.04296161 (init = 10)
    C0:      1.26289805 (init = 5)
    R1:      0.63653349 (init = 0.587)
    R3:      0.60694072 (init = 0.3125)
    R4:      0.11924779 (init = 0.1666)
    R5:      2.7998e-07 (init = 0.1)
    R6:      0.58190868 (init = 0.2)
    R7:      0.49973503 (init = 0.4)
    R8:      9.4685e-07 (init = 0.125)
    alpha:   9.7636e-05 (init = 0.09)
    beta:    0.08512620 (init = 0.25)
    rho:     0.55511880 (init = 0.2)
    theta:   0.08153075 (init = 0.26)
    delta:   0.38812246 (init = 0.77)
    d:       1.4235e-07 (init = 0.99)
```

So all values have changed significantly from the initial values.
I read in other posts that the problem might be that some parameters correlate very strongly. To eliminate this possibility, I set for all but two parameters `parameters['...'].vary = False`, which did not change the error. I did this for different sets of 'two' parameters.

**Now, if I instead follow the second approach:**
I add the lines:

```
min = lmfit.Minimizer(func,params=parameters,fcn_args=np.arange(0,78, 1))
min.minimize(method='leastsq')
ci = lmfit.conf_interval(min)
lmfit.report_ci(ci)
```

So now I only minimize my function. I will later subtract the `total_data_array` to minimize the difference between my function and the data and obtain a curve fit. For now, I just want to get this to work. I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\fitting2.py", line 134, in <module>
    min.minimize(method='leastsq')
  File "...\lmfit\minimizer.py", line 2345, in minimize
    return function(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\lmfit\minimizer.py", line 1651, in leastsq
    lsout = scipy_leastsq(self.__residual, variables, **lskws)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py", line 415, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py", line 25, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:...\lmfit\minimizer.py", line 548, in __residual
    out = self.userfcn(params, *self.userargs, **self.userkws)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: func() takes 17 positional arguments but 79 were given
```

so already the minimisation seems to fail. Changing `fcn_args=` to `args=` as parameter in the `minimize()` function yields instead the error:

```
File "...\fitting2.py", line 147, in <module>
    min.minimize(method='leastsq')
  File "...\lmfit\minimizer.py", line 2345, in minimize
    return function(**kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\lmfit\minimizer.py", line 1651, in leastsq
    lsout = scipy_leastsq(self.__residual, variables, **lskws)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py", line 415, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\scipy\optimize\_minpack_py.py", line 25, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\lmfit\minimizer.py", line 530, in __residual
    if apply_bounds_transformation:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So it might be that the problem lies in some keyword-arguments that need to be passed to `minimize()`. But I don't know what to pass as keywords or why.
I appreciate any help :)

Comment: 'playing around' is not good programming practice.  You should understand what you are doing, and why.  Getting the number of parameters right requires paying attention to how they are passed to your `func`.  That's a matter of carefully reading the docs, and keeping track of what your `func` needs.  As for the ambiguity error, you don't provide any stack trace, so we can't say what's causing it.  Uusually it means you supply an array to some line of code that expects a simple True/False value, such as a `if` or `or`.

Comment: Thanks for the Input. I have edited my post

Comment: I would not necessarily dismiss "playing around" ;)  But I would suggest going back to the first fit that you said "worked".  Why can't you get confidence intervals for that fit?  You did not show a fit report.  You also did not show anything even approaching a complete example. What did you try to get confidence intervals?  Your second example just shows a programming error that seems pretty clear, but without showing any code, you cannot expect anyone to be able to help you with that.

Comment: uh, well, what gets printed in your fit report?  Does your fit "work " to change all the variables away from their initial values? What the heck is your `linearize()` meant to do?   That seems sort of odd to me.

Comment: @MNewville I added a fit report. Yes, the fit changes every single parameter. But I remember that when I chose different initial values a few days ago, the last two parameters remained unchanged. I did not know exactly if model.fit() would evaluate also at float values in between the integers. So I used the linearize fct. And afterwards I did not delete it because it didn't hurt. Btw thanks alot for trying to help ! Appreciate it.

Comment: @MNewville removing the linearization function changed nothing

Comment: I guess `ci = lmfit.conf_interval(results, results)` might work. To get an answer that is not a "guess", please provide [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Often, creating a reproducible example will help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give two attempts at using lmfit. The first one is correct, and the fit runs.  The second, using lmfit.Minimize does not work because your `func` is a model function not an objective function: it does not have the same call signature, which is what the exceptions you are seeing tell you.  But there is no point in trying lmfit.Minimize anyway.  The lmfit.Model runs, it just tells you that it cannot estimate uncertainties.  Also FWIW, there is no point in running `lmfit.conf_interval` if the initial fit cannot estimate uncertainties.  That will not "fix the problem".

As you will have read in the lmfit [FAQ](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/faq.html), there are a few reasons why uncertainties sometimes cannot be estimated, but they all derive from the same root cause: small changes to the value of one or more of the parameters has no noticeable effect on the fit. When that happens, the covariance matrix cannot be determined -- the fit algorithm has decided that at least one of the parameters is not actually affecting the fit.
One reason that can happen is that a parameter gets stuck at a boundary or initial value.  That does not seem to be the case for your fit.   Another possibility is that one or more parameters have reached such extreme values (say, nearly 0) that other parameters no longer have an effect on the fit.  Imagine that you are modeling a peak with a center, width, and height.  If the height value moves to zero, it doesn't really matter what the width or center value is, that model will just be zero.

I guess that is what is happening with your fit.  The values for several of your parameters go to ~1e-7 level -- 5 or more orders of magnitude smaller than your initial estimate of them.

I must say that you do not describe your model at all, and are running some external program and then doing some fairly clunky parsing of a text of results.  We don't know what any of that is doing.  So, there is no way for anyone else to know that if, say, `d` goes from 0.99 to 1.4-e7, the rest of the model even makes sense.  Maybe you know that.
Anyway, that is where I would start looking.  It seems likely that you have not run your model with initial values (or final values) and plotted the results: that is always highly recommended to check that your initial values are reasonable.  With such a large value of Chi-square and a value of R so far from 1, it would be easy to just assert that you have a terrible fit.  If you don't have a good fit, uncertainties would be meaningless anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I see your reasoning and that is probably the best answer that can be given. The model is extremely complicated so I don't think it would make much sense to post it.  But I have an idea now how to go on with the project :)

Comment: @PaulJoh it is okay that you cannot post the model of "run complex program, parse results". It's just that we have to assume that this is all being done well.  And, maybe that model is so opaque that it is not obvious what "R5 goes to 0" actually means for the total result.  So, you may need to spend some time (I might say "playing around" ;) ) running the model with various inputs to see if it is doing what you expect, and if the fit is actually any good.